# VBA from excel 2010 win not work on excel 2011 mac

Tags: excel, macos, vba

excuse my english, it is not good, but I hope you can understand me.

I have a problem with my VBA code that I use in Excel 2010 on windows without problems, but his not working on mac excel 2011.
I have changed from pc to mac and I don't know the mac system and I not can find the solution.

this is my code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim strJahrgang As String
Dim strKlasse As String
Dim strNr As String
Dim mPath As String
Dim mFoto As String
mPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Foto"
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
strJahrgang = Worksheets("Register").Range("D18")
strKlasse = Worksheets("Register").Range("E36")
' Schleife über alle Tabellenblätter
For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
    ' Tabellenname enthält "schüler_"
    If InStr(Sheets(i).Name, "schüler_") > 0 Then
        With Sheets(i)
            ' Nr. aus dem Tabellennamen
            strNr = Format(Application.Substitute(.Name, "schüler_", ""), "00")
            ' Bildnamen zusammensetzen
            mFoto = strJahrgang & " Klasse " & strKlasse & " - " & strNr & " " & _
                .Cells(1, 5) & " " & .Cells(1, 8)
            ' in laufender Tabelle ist kein Bild vorhanden
            If .Shapes.Count = 0 Then
                ' benötigtes Bild ist im Ornder vorhanden
                If Dir(mPath & "\" & mFoto & ".jpg") <> "" Then
                    .Pictures.Insert (mPath & "\" & mFoto & ".jpg")
                    With .Pictures(.Pictures.Count)
                        .Top = Range("G5").Top
                        .Left = Range("G5").Left
                        .Height = Range("G5:G12").Height
                        .Width = Range("G5:J5").Width
                    End With
                    DoEvents
                ' Bild ist im Ordner nicht mehr vorhanden
                Else
                    ' Bild löschen
                    If .Shapes.Count > 0 Then .Shapes(1).Delete
                End If
            ' in laufender Tabelle ist Bild vorhanden
            Else
                ' wenn Bild im Ordner nicht merh vorhanden dann Bild löschen
                If Dir(mPath & "\" & mFoto & ".jpg") = "" Then .Shapes(1).Delete
            End If
            mFoto = ""
        End With
    End If
Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

End Sub

I have understand the mac use ":" where win use "/", so I think to must change "/" with ":".
my problem is a runtime error 68 on this line 
`If Dir(mPath & "\" & mFoto & ".jpg") <> "" Then
                        .Pictures.Insert (mPath & "\" & mFoto & ".jpg")`

I think mac don't like the command "Dir" and can not find the directory "Foto". probably I must use a MacID but I don't know how I must use it and my english to understand it are to bad.

I use the code to insert automatically the photo from my students in the schoolregister. the code search the schoolyear on the page "register" cell e18 and the class in cell e36. in page "schüler_1", "schüler_2" etc. in the cells e1 he found the last name and h1 first name from evrey stundent. With this informations the code search in the order "Foto" that stay in the same place how the excelfile the right foto of the stundents and insert it on cells g5:j12. example "2014-15 klasse 1a - 01 Ciccio Bello"

I hope someone can please help me, thanks.
dan

Comment: Use Application.PathSeparator, which returns ":" for Mac and "\" for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

[This link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj614412(v=office.14).aspx#odc_xl14_ta_PerformFileFolderOpers_Intro) should give you the information you require for file and folder operations on the Mac.

**EDIT**

@T J Noted and thank you

@muma I don't use the Mac for VBA much so may not be able to respond in great detail.  However, from the link, it seems you require a function to test for files/folders.  Apparently Mac has difficulty with long file names?

For your specific Q, the below test code and function should enable you to test whether a file or folder exists.  The first argument in the function determines whether the check is for a file or folder: 1 = file, 2 = folder.  You will need to provide your own path/filename in the function call.  My example file name just happens to be 'Workbook2.csv' in the code below.

```
Sub macTest()
Dim isfl As Boolean

    If FileOrFolderExistsOnMac(1, "<your disk name>:Users:<your user name>:Documents:Workbook2.csv") Then
        MsgBox "Yes it exists"
    Else
        MsgBox "Sorry file doesn't exist"
    End If

End Sub

Function FileOrFolderExistsOnMac(FileOrFolder As Long, FileOrFolderstr As String) As Boolean
'By Ron de Bruin
'30-July-2012
'Function to test whether a file or folder exist on a Mac.
'Uses AppleScript to avoid the problem with long file names.
    Dim ScriptToCheckFileFolder As String
    ScriptToCheckFileFolder = "tell application " & Chr(34) & "Finder" & Chr(34) & Chr(13)
    If FileOrFolder = 1 Then
        ScriptToCheckFileFolder = ScriptToCheckFileFolder & "exists file " & _
        Chr(34) & FileOrFolderstr & Chr(34) & Chr(13)
    Else
        ScriptToCheckFileFolder = ScriptToCheckFileFolder & "exists folder " & _
        Chr(34) & FileOrFolderstr & Chr(34) & Chr(13)
    End If
    ScriptToCheckFileFolder = ScriptToCheckFileFolder & "end tell" & Chr(13)
    FileOrFolderExistsOnMac = MacScript(ScriptToCheckFileFolder)
End Function
```

Comment: i have chang the code with If Dir(mPfad, MacID("jpg")) <> "" Then but thez don't work :(